# Partial View is not loaded after main page is rendered

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor-pages

I have a razor main page with a selector that is loaded with the `OnGet()` event, when the user clicks in a value of this selector a jQuery function is called to load a partial view with some values.

Everything works fine here, but now I want to show the partial view with the values of the first value from the selector when the page is rendered.

In order to do that a create this jQuery function (which is exactly the same that I use for load the partial view when the user clicks on the selector):

```
<div id="partialView"></div>

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    //These are hidden inputs for obtain the values                                        
    var value1 = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("value2").value;

    var url = '/(CONTROLLER)/(ACTION)/' + value1 + '/' + @Model.Id + '/' + value2 + '/';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#partialview').html(data);
        }
    });
})
```

If I put a breakpoint in the controller I can see that the function is hit, but the partial view is not shown after it finished.

I think the problem could be related that the page hasn't finished rendering when the jQuery function is being invoked but I'm not sure.

Comment: "*the page didn't finish to render when the jquery function is being invoked*" - that's what `doc.ready` is for, which you are using. This could be the case if you have some *other* code that dynamically loads `#partialview` - check your selector `console.log($("[id=partialview]").length)` just before you set `.html(data)` - if its 0 then that element doesn't exist.   If it's more than 1 then you have multiple elements with the same ID and you're probably updating the wrong one.  If it's one, then that elment is probably *hidden* - change to `..html(data).show()`

Comment: Also, add debugging to confirm that the jquery gets the result `console.log(data)`.   You can also use network tools to check.

Comment: Using the console.log(data) into the success print the HTML code of my partial view, but the view is not showed unless I click in the selector.

Comment: Sounds like your #partialview is hidden and you have some *other* code that shows it when you click.  Please [edit] your code and provide a *complete* snippet (mock the ajax call) that *demonstrates* the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: I have a repository in which I reproduce the problem that I have, if you want you could take a look to see the issue.

https://github.com/J003-3/RazorPageIssue

Comment: Wouldn't the value1 and value2 be empty on document.ready? Where are you assigning them values?

Comment: You talk a lot about view/partial view etc. but have none IN your question (links don't count for this as they can change or be removed later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that your markup includes this:

`<div id="partialView"></div>`

`$('#partialview').html(data);`

should be

`$('#partialView').html(data);`

with a capital `V`. Selectors are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes!! That was the problem, thank you so much. Just a simple thing but I couldn't find the problem.